# Tableau online Migration

Tags: tableau-api

After I migrated to tableau online and publish the workbook, the workbook, as well as the views, are showing in the subscription email. I have chosen subscribe Workbook option.

For example, if there are 5 workbooks and 3 views in each workbook, in the subscription email I'm getting 5 workbooks + 15 views. ideally, it should be only 5 workbooks.

When used in tableau server, this was working properly. Anyone knows how to rectify this?

Comment: Your question is confusing. You said you have subscribed to the workbook and the workbook is showing in the subscription email. What would you expect to have happen?

Comment: Some comparison screenshots showing expected and unexpected behaviour would be useful here

Comment: @SamM In the subscription email, workbook, as well as the individual views, are present. for example, if there are 5 workbooks and 3 views in each workbook, in the subscription email I'm getting 5 workbook + 15 views. ideally it should be only 5 workbook

Comment: @DJo I think you are using the word workbook incorrectly, which is why I'm confused. You can't have 5 workbooks in a single subscription email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the unwanted sheets are deleted and hiding all the sheets used in the workbook it works as expected. The subscription emails are generated correctly also the workbooks are shown correctly.